# Mergesort lines from a .txt file

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I've a file with multiple sorted lines.
Now I want to sort all this lines in to one merged line in a new file. Without loading all the numbers at once.

This is a part of my file:

```html
12,86,280,304,350,359,371,391,405,548,
255,264,325,346,435,466,483,
39,114,214,298,317,377,428,438,575,
35,165,183,281,336,367,386,418,438,593,
44,77,97,117,122,156,251,415,533,
109,155,163,172,212,226,340,358,452,577,592,
33,74,91,204,256,307,357,388,534,552,554,570,
50,99,246,309,345,358,395,405,419,425,566,
```

Now I want to merge sort those, so at first I need to know how much lines the file has. Then I need to get all the first elements and compare them. The lowest I write to the new file. Then I've to get the second number from the line I just had written away. And compare them with the first numbers of the other lines. How do I do this. I've written a Mergesort for Arraylists:

```js
      //as long as there is unsorted data
        while (listOfOutputs.size() > 0) {
            //Set the lowest undefined
            List<Integer> lowest = null;
            for (List<Integer> list : listOfOutputs) {
                //if the lowest is undefined, I'm the lowest
                if (lowest == null) {
                    lowest = list;
                    //Else am I lower then the lowest? Then I'm the lowest
                } else if (list.get(0) < lowest.get(0)) {
                    lowest = list;
                }
            }

            //Finally the lowest is added to the sorted list and removed to from his own list.
            assert lowest != null;
            sortedList.add(lowest.remove(0));

            //Is the size of the list which contained to lowest now 0, remove him from the listOfOutputs
            if (lowest.size() == 0) listOfOutputs.remove(lowest);
        }
```

But I don't know how to rewrite this into one that sorts my file. How do I do this, without loading them in lists.

Sven

Comment: Would it be OK to simply read each line, parsing each line as you read and append every parsed integer to a list, and finally sort that entire list in one go at the end?

Comment: Is your data too large to fit into memory? Is that why you don't want to just load all the data into a single array and sort it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple 2 way merge to merge 2 lines at a time into a single lines, repeating the process until a single sorted line is produced.

or

Assuming k is the number of lines, you can implement a k way merge, probably using a heap to optimize the find which line has the smallest first element. Each heap element contains a reference to line and equivalent of an index (or pointer) to the current element for that line. The heap is ordered by the current elements of each line so that the head of the heap references the line with the current smallest element. The heap is initialized by the first elements of all k lines.

For each merge step, the line from the head of the heap (the line with the smallest element) is removed, that smallest element appended to the output line, and the line that had the smallest element is added back into the heap based on its next element.

When the end of a line is reached, the merge is reduced to a k-1 way merge, eventually ending up with just a single line that is copied to the merged output.

Comment: This is possible, but not what I want. Can you tell me how do I get, the count of elements in a row?

Comment: @SvenOrdelman - You can scan the line looking for a line terminator, usually a new line character, '\n'. This may not be needed, if the end of a line can be determined when advancing to the next element in a line during the merge process, since the merge process only needs to know if there's an element in a line or if the end of a line has been reached.